# Row yielded no matching during look up

Tags: sql, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a job that runs a package, the job used to run well with no issue but today one of the package failed, and it’s Csv source -> lookup -> oledb destination. Error is **Row yielded no matching look up.** 
I have tried to
Ltrim Rtrim, 
Change the mataddat to false, but still didn’t work. Any ideas please? Thank you.

Comment: And my source and destination have the same value. And lookup is set to fail components.

Comment: What are the data types of the source and destination?

Comment: My assumption is that you're hitting a difference in character case https://stackoverflow.com/a/26722035/181965

Answer (score 3):

The error is self explanatory. Your lookup does not find a matching value and it fails because that is what you instructed it to do

[image]

You can change it to ignore failures (similarly to what a left join would work) 
You can redirect it to an error output and then deal with it on the error output flow.
You can redirect it to a no match output which will gives you the option to create a new flow from this component for the non matching entries.

Comment: Yes I have thought Of that too, but my source and destination are matching.

Comment: It doesn't match. That's what you have to figure out. My guess is a different char. Also, redirect output so you can figure out if it is just problem or many.

Comment: Yes, i redirect the output and I figured it out, thanks.